# Why do tabs in YAML work some but not at all times?

Tags: file-format, ansible, yaml

We've used tab-characters in some of YAML-files here:

```
host:   "foo"
port:   8011
p:      "bar"
```

For some reason, the same version of Ansible running the same playbook works just fine with these files for some users, but complains about "invalid characters" for others:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found character '\t' that cannot start any token

The error appears to have been in '.../playbooks/roles/native-package/defaults/main.yml': line 1, column
8, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


tmpdir: >-
       ^ here
There appears to be a tab character at the start of the line.

YAML does not use tabs for formatting. Tabs should be replaced with spaces.

For example:
    - name: update tooling
      vars:
        version: 1.2.3
#    ^--- there is a tab there.

Should be written as:
    - name: update tooling
      vars:
        version: 1.2.3
# ^--- all spaces here.
```

I'm not asking, whether tabs are "better" than spaces -- but I'd like to understand the inconsistency...

Comment: Ansible uses `pyyaml` for parsing, which will use libYAML _if_ it's present, but includes it's own fallback parser that gets used if the system doesn't have libYAML.  It sounds like either libYAML or the pyyaml fallback parser has an issue with tabs.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like all systems involved have PyYAML installed - 3.13 or 3.12...

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs or extensions may be reading or converting tabs to spaces, or spaces to tabs. Check the tab settings showing in the files for each user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).